# OpenSSL install error - symbolic link not created

Tags: linux, openssl, symlink

I am currently trying to install OpenSSL on Centos7 from source. I am currently logged in as `root`. When I run the `./config` command, I get a basket full of errors saying...

```
 `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'xxxxx.c': Operation not supported`
```

I can't seem to find anything on how to fix this issue. Not sure if I'm looking in the wrong place or if its the end of the day frustrations getting the best of me. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Why are you installing from source?

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono the company proxy wont allow pip to work..

Comment: OpenSSL is an RPM. Do you have access to the RPM?

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono I ended up moving the directory out of my VM's shared folder to a new location. It seems to be installing fine now. I don't guess the symlink works when its in a shared folder.